# Accessing WCF hosted in Windows Service in a silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I have hosted my Wcf services in a windows services, i am able to use it without any issue in my test console application, but when i try using the same service by using service reference in my silverlight application, it is giving me error.

ServiceReferences.ClientConfig has this entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        ...
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/myservices/myservice/"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_myservice"
          contract="ServiceReference1.myservice" name="NetTcpBinding_myservice">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am getting this error:
Unrecognized element 'netTcpBinding' in service reference configuration. Note that only a subset of the Windows Communication Foundation configuration functionality is available in Silverlight.
Will appreciate your help..

Alpee

Answer (score 0):

Have you Installed `WCF Non-HTTP Activation` on your IIS?

Found this rather good article on using NetTcpBinding with WCF and Silverlight: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311250/NetTcpBinding-Configurations-for-WCF-and-Silverlig

The other thing I noted is that apparently you can't specify security options with Silverlight and netTcp, so have to specify an insecure binding (from that same example):

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="InsecureTcp" receiveTimeout="Infinite">
          <security mode="None"/>                                    
        </binding>                                                   
      </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```